# Why is there such a big space between my content and the screen on small sized devices

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am building a fake game-selling boutique using NextJs and Tailwindcss. The other day while testing my website I noticed that on smaller screens there seems to be a big gap between my main content and the rest of the screen. I don't really get why my content doesn't take the width of all the screen.

[Here is a screenshot from my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38INW.png)

[Here is a screenshot from my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63iOD.jpg)

I'm guessing they could be various reasons for this behavior but I can't really figure what's happening here. I showed screenshots of the homepage but all pages of the site show a simmilar gap on mobile devices. The code is fairly long so I will share the code for the homepage below, the rest of the code can be seen on [the github page for the project here](https://github.com/yoansj/yoyo-games), also the project is hosted [here on vercel](https://yoyo-games.vercel.app/)

**Here is the code for the Homepage [click here for github link](https://github.com/yoansj/yoyo-games/blob/main/pages/index.tsx)**

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import MyMetaTags from "../components/MyMetaTags";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import GameCard from "../components/GameCard";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import UserReview from "../components/UserReview";
import games from "../data/games";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="w-screen">
      <Head>
        <MyMetaTags />
        <title>Yoyo Games</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Yoyo Games" />
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content="Here at Yoyo Games we provide the best games for the best players"
        />
        <meta property="og:image" content="/Facebook-cover.png" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Here at Yoyo Games we provide the best games for the best players"
        />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <main className="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-col justify-center items-center mt-10">
        <h1 className="text-3xl text-center whitespace-pre-line max-w-4xl font-mono">
          Here at Yoyo Games we provide the best games for the best players.{" "}
          <br />
          Want the lastest best selling game ? <br />
          Check below or use our buttons on top ! <br />
          Need that hardware to play ? We sell it too ! <br />
          At Yoyo Games you're the{" "}
          <span className="text-red-600 uppercase hover:animate-pulse cursor-crosshair">
            boss
          </span>
          .
        </h1>
        <div className="w-4/5 lg:h-24 mt-10">
          <div className="bg-purple-500 w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center">
            <h1 className="text-white font-bold text-4xl text-center lg:pt-3">
              Still not convinced ? Check our bestsellers below
            </h1>
            <h2 className="text-white text-base text-center italic">
              (Dont worry they will convince you)
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
          <GameCard game={games[2]} />
          <GameCard game={games[1]} />
          <GameCard game={games[2]} />
          <GameCard game={games[1]} />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
          <GameCard game={games[2]} />
          <GameCard game={games[1]} />
          <GameCard game={games[2]} />
          <GameCard game={games[1]} />
        </div>
        <div className="w-4/5 lg:h-24 mt-10 h-32">
          <div className="bg-purple-500 w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center">
            <h1 className="text-white font-bold text-4xl text-center lg:pt-3">
              Not convinced again ? you're hard{" "}
              <span className="text-red-600 uppercase hover:animate-pulse cursor-crosshair">
                boss
              </span>{" "}
              check our reviews below
            </h1>
            <h2 className="text-white text-base text-center italic">
              (They should convince yout this time)
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="mt-10 flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-center align-middle">
            <UserReview
              imageUrl="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/017/539/captain_falcon.jpg"
              name="Captain Falcon"
              quote="10/10 would wo again they showed me their moves. (They also sell F-Zero games)"
              title="Super Smash Bros character"
            />
            <UserReview
              imageUrl="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              name="Kai'Sa FTW"
              quote="Yoyo Games is great, they don't sell Kai'Sa merch yet nor Riot Points card but they sell cool games it's already a great start i'd say."
              title="Kai'Sa main and LoL player"
            />
            <UserReview
              imageUrl="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/portrait-ecstatic-gamer-guy-headphones-screaming-rejoi-portrait-ecstatic-gamer-guy-headphones-screaming-127296321.jpg"
              name="Gamer guy"
              quote="I love games ! I am also deeply into E-sports ! #KCORP FTW !"
              title="E-Sports pro gamer"
            />
            <UserReview
              imageUrl="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/06/ab/f506ab054c29a532edbcb61ebcc7601f.png"
              name="Hatsune Miku"
              quote="彼らはすぐにそのウェブサイトで私のゲームを売るはずなので、ええ、私は間違いなくニャをお勧めします！"
              title="VOCALOID"
            />
          </ul>
          <ul className="mt-9 mb-20 flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-center align-middle">
            <UserReview
              imageUrl="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/017/539/captain_falcon.jpg"
              name="Captain Falcon"
              quote="10/10 would wo again they showed me their moves. (They also sell F-Zero games)"
              title="Super Smash Bros character"
            />
            <UserReview
              imageUrl="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              name="Kai'Sa FTW"
              quote="Yoyo Games is great, they don't sell Kai'Sa merch yet nor Riot Points card but they sell cool games it's already a great start i'd say."
              title="Kai'Sa main and LoL player"
            />
            <UserReview
              imageUrl="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/portrait-ecstatic-gamer-guy-headphones-screaming-rejoi-portrait-ecstatic-gamer-guy-headphones-screaming-127296321.jpg"
              name="Gamer guy"
              quote="I love games ! I am also deeply into E-sports ! #KCORP FTW !"
              title="E-Sports pro gamer"
            />
            <UserReview
              imageUrl="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/06/ab/f506ab054c29a532edbcb61ebcc7601f.png"
              name="Hatsune Miku"
              quote="彼らはすぐにそのウェブサイトで私のゲームを売るはずなので、ええ、私は間違いなくニャをお勧めします！"
              title="VOCALOID"
            />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help, links, informations or comments are appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: @SeanW I just tried but it produces the same result

Comment: Still doesn't do much, the gap still shows on mobile devices

Comment: I just looked at your app https://yoyo-games.vercel.app/ - you need to remove the negative margins in your header.  The two four-column grids in the body and one in the footer are shrinking your content.  I'm not sure how to fix it other than replacing the grid with tailwind columns or flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [file](https://github.com/yoansj/yoyo-games/blob/main/components/GameCard.tsx) line 54 is causing the issue.

w-80 is 20rem, you might want to revisit the structure here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, this isn't really an answer for me because it does reduce the gap but the gap is still there. Also if you try on other pages without the GameCard component a gap is still there but not as big. Also can you give more explanation on why this works ? Thank you